# Additional code not working on all buttons

Tags: html, css, button, woocommerce

I'm desperately learning as I go here but am stumped at this one...

I have this code in my Additional CSS WP panel:

```html
.woocommerce #content input.button.alt:hover, .woocommerce #respond input#submit.alt:hover, .woocommerce a.button.alt:hover, .woocommerce button.button.alt:hover, .woocommerce input.button.alt:hover, .woocommerce-page #content input.button.alt:hover, .woocommerce-page #respond input#submit.alt:hover, .woocommerce-page a.button.alt:hover, .woocommerce-page button.button.alt:hover, .woocommerce-page input.button.alt:hover

{

background: #930275 !important;

background-color: #930275 !important;

color:white !important;

text-shadow: transparent !important;

box-shadow: none;

border-color: #930275 !important;

}
```

But only one section of my account buttons are behaving correctly, they should all look like this on hover (pink with white text):

[image]

But instead some of them still look like this:

[image]

Would someone be able to explain what I'm doing wrong?

I think the classes I need to edit are these;

woocommerce-button button view
woocommerce-Button button

Thank you :D

UPDATE: Here's a screenshot from the inspect pane:

[image]

Comment: Did you check your CSS class and selector order? Inspect elements that aren't working those have the correct class or not.

Comment: Right click on "VIEW" button, click "Inspect", go to the CSS panel and send us a screenshot of the CSS class/es. This should help us find the right selector

Comment: @businessbloomer - Hey, thanks so much for your reply, I've just updated my question with a screenshot of the inspect pane - I thought the correct selector would be: 

woocommerce-button button view

But I'm just grasping at straws as I dont actullay understand too much when it comes to coding!

Comment: @MainulHasan - thanks for your reply - I'm afraid I'm learning all of this as I go and it's pretty much trial and error if any code I add/change works and with that in mind I dont actually have a clue about what the CCS class and Selector order mean?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot, the following should work.

Also, [!important should not be used in CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp). If the following doesn't work, try prepend "body" to the selector (so it would become "body .woocommerce-button.button").

```
.woocommerce a.button:hover {
   background: #930275;
   background-color: #930275;
   color:white;
   text-shadow: none;
   box-shadow: none;
   border-color: #930275;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again @businessbloomer, unfortunately it hasn't worked which makes me wonder just how messed up my site really is... but I've just whizzed you an email about hiring your services. Cheers, Emily.